# Prism Xamarin 6.2 IDependencyService in service

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, prism

I'm using SQLite for via ISQLite interface which is implemented on the standard way via [assembly: Dependency(typeof(SQLite_iOS))] ...

but also I'm trying to implement data access model via the Repository pattern

My BaseRepository class  looks like this

```
public abstract class BaseRepository<TEntity, TKey> : IRepository<TEntity, TKey> where TEntity : class, new()
{
    private readonly SQLiteAsyncConnection _connection;

    protected BaseRepository(ISQLite sqlite)
    {
        _connection = sqlite.GetAsyncConnection();

        _connection.CreateTableAsync<TEntity>().Wait();
    }
```

For each model I have an implementation of the BaseRepository class

```
public class SectorsRepository : BaseRepository<Sectors, int>, ISectorsRepository
{
    public SectorsRepository(ISQLite context)
        : base(context)
    {

    }
}
```

I'm now struggling how to register each Repository class. Obviously, this doesn't work as I don't have an instance of dependencyService;

```
protected override void RegisterTypes()
    {

        Container.RegisterType<ISectorsRepository, SectorsRepository>(new InjectionConstructor(dependencyService.Get<ISQLite>()));
}
```

Any idea?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be using DependencyService at all.  It's not needed.  You already have a true DI container.  Use that instead.  Even if you do use the DependencyService attribute in your platform projects, you don't need to resolve them by calling the DependencyService.  Prism will automatically resolve them for you.  You also shouldn't be manually injecting anything into your ctor, because your container will do this for you automatically as long as you have registered your services with the container.

Comment: Thanks! Didn't know that prism automatically resolves them. At the end my code transformed to:
Container.RegisterType<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>();

Answer (score 0):

To answer myself. This piece of code made it to work. The only thing I don't like is manual instancing of DependencyService. Does anyone has more elegant solution?

thanks

```
protected override void RegisterTypes()
        {
            DependencyService ds = new DependencyService();
            Container.RegisterType<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>(new InjectionConstructor(ds.Get<ISQLite>()));
....
}
```